# I think I am using the splice method incorrectly

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am trying to solve a problem and I have having a hard time getting the answer from my splice method. I am trying to pull out all the odd numbers from an array, put them in order, and place them back in the array while leaving the even numbers in place. In my last for loop I am attempting to use splice to get the index of the current odd number, remove it, and put the sorted odd number back in with via a variable. It's not going the way I intended. Thanks for any help I can get.

```
function sortArray(array) {

  var odds = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    if (array[i] % 2 !== 0) {

      odds.push(array[i]);

    }

  }

  odds.sort();

  console.log('array', array)

  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

    var x = 0;

    if (array[i] % 2 !== 0) {

      x = odds.shift();

      console.log('x', x)

      array.splice(i, 1, x); <-- I think this is my problem...maybe...

      console.log('array 2', array)

    }

  }

  console.log(array)

  return array;

}


sortArray([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4])
```

These are the console logs I am getting from it:

```
array [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4 ]

x 1

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 1 ]

x 3

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 3 ]

x 5

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, 5 ]

x undefined

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, undefined ]

x undefined

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, undefined ]

x undefined

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, undefined ]

x undefined

array 2 [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, undefined ]

[ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, undefined ]

=> [ 5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4, undefined ]
```

Comment: You're using i to refer to indices within the j loop.

Answer (score 0):

splice expect two arguments

1. Index of element from where you want to start deletion.
2. Number of items to be deleted.

so in your code.
Step-1 : create Odd number array 
Step-2 : sort it 
Step-3 : remove odd number from existing array
step-4 : concat odd number array to the end of existing array.

Step-1 & 2 are fine

for step -3 & 4

```
for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

  var x = 0;

  if (array[j] % 2 !== 0) {

     array.splice(j, 1); 
  }
}
 array = array.concat(odds);
```